# Xamarin runtime vs Dalvik

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, dalvik

I am looking for alternatives to native development for the 3 big mobile ecosystems, and got hit by Xamarin Studio.

Simple question, does Xamarin runtime "pass over (substitute)" the Dalvik VM in Android? 
Another simple question, does Xamarin generates binary code only for ARM processors? And the Intel Atom mobile phones, do not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> does Xamarin runtime "pass over (substitute)" the Dalvik VM in Android?

No, Xamarin ship an embedded C# runtime with your Application, but the access for the java Resources are done just by binding.

> Another simple question, does Xamarin generates binary code only for ARM processors?

No. Your apk will have the Xamarin Runtime for arm6, arm7 and x86 (used in Intel Atom) by default. You can also include the runtime for arm64 e x86_64 or remove any of those.

> And the Intel Atom mobile phones, do not work?

As I said before, it does work on x86 architecture, include Intel Atom

Comment: would it be possible to reduce the size of an apk by removing support for arm6 and x86?

Comment: @Ohiovr Yes, you can configure this in the Android project properties